# How can I verify a pem_cert and signiture (RSA-SHA1)?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to check if a signature is valid, in Node.js I would use

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_verify_verify_object_signature_signatureencoding

I can't seem to find anything for crystal that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not implemented in the standard library, but we can find a shard that does it: [openssl_ext](https://github.com/randomstate/openssl_ext). This shards closely resembles the Ruby API, so let's get going!

First we need a key:

```
$ openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -out key.pem
$ openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout -out pub.pem
```

Then we need to create a shard and add the dependency:

```
$ shards init
$ $EDITOR shards.yml
```

```yml
dependencies:
   openssl_ext:
      github: randomstate/openssl_ext
```

```
$ shards
```

A small program to sign something:

```
$ $EDITOR sign.cr
```

```
require "openssl_ext"
require "base64"

private_key = OpenSSL::RSA.new File.read(ARGV[0])
digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new("SHA1")

data = ARGV[1]
signature = private_key.sign digest, data

puts Base64.encode signature
```

```
$ crystal build sign.cr
```

And a small program to verify a signature:

```
$ $EDITOR verify.cr
```

```
require "openssl_ext"
require "base64"

public_key = OpenSSL::RSA.new File.read(ARGV[0]), is_private: false
digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new("SHA1")

data = ARGV[1]
signature = Base64.decode STDIN.gets_to_end

puts public_key.verify(digest, signature, data) ? "Valid" : "Invalid"
```

```
$ crystal build verify.cr
```

Let's test our work:

```
$ ./sign key.pem Hello | ./verify pub.pem Hello
Valid
$ ./sign key.pem Hello | ./verify pub.pem Bye
Invalid
```